# How can I delete a SAFEARRAY returned from a .NET function in native code?

Tags: .net, com-interop, safearray

I'm hosting a .NET library in my C++ program using the following methods, though not an exhaustive list:

```
CorBindToRuntimeEx()
GetDefaultDomain()
CreateInstance()
GetIDsOfNames()
```

And eventually a call to `Invoke()`.

This works well enough, but I'm leaking memory whenever a .NET function returns an array, such as:

```
public int[] getArray() { int[] i = { 0, 1, 2, 3 }; return i; }
```

In this case, the function returns a `VARIANT` of type `VT_SAFEARRAY|VT_I4`. I've tried `delete` and `delete[]` on both the descriptor and pvData member, and this always fails. I've tried to `SafeArrayDestroy()` the descriptor, which succeeds but corrupts the heap. I can call `SafeArrayDestroyData()` on `variant.parray->pvData` which works fine, but `SafeArrayDestroyDescriptor()` again corrupts the heap. I'm still leaking the array descriptors.

So, how can I deallocate the SAFEARRAY descriptor and plug this memory leak?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Impossible to guess without seeing code.  The heap might have been corrupted long before anyway.

You should use VariantClear().

Comment: Thank you for that. VariantClear() paired with VariantInit() fixed the leaks. I wish I had found documentation about that earlier.